# GMongo instance undefined from gremlin shell in neo4j

Tags: mongodb, groovy, neo4j, gremlin, titan

I am trying to load the data from mongodb database from the Gremlin shell in neo4j in order to create a graph databse from it. The detail is explained in [gremlin-mongodb](http://thinkaurelius.com/2013/02/04/polyglot-persistence-and-query-with-gremlin/). To get started, I downloaded the GMongo jar file fom [GMongo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gmongo/gmongo) and ran the following codes in Gremlin shell in Neo4j web admin console

```
gremlin> import com.gmongo.GMongo
gremlin> mongo = new GMongo()
```

The import command works and imports the packages but the second line failed with message being undefined.   I also tried to import the following packages but that did not work either.

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject
import com.mongodb.DBObject
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: What's the actual failure?

Comment: Also, did you download the dependencies for GMongo as well? http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gmongo/gmongo/1.1

Comment: Gremlin just says "undefined"

Comment: The failure is an "undefined" message in Gremlin. No I did not add the dependencies, does it mean I have to copy the POM file somewhere? I am not a java person , could you please comment.

Comment: Note that you need both the GMongo jar AND the java mongo driver it depends on: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to highlight the answer that  [stephen mallette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831717/stephen-mallette) provided for this question and also many thanks to tim_yates and most of Marko Rodrigez.
we need to copy both the GMongo jar file from [Gmongo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gmongo/gmongo) as well as [Mongo java driver](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.9.0) and put them under lib directory. Thanks again Stephen.

Comment: Note that, as of Gremlin 2.4.0, in addition to manually copying jars into the Gremlin path (which can lead to troubles like this one), you can now use Grape to handle dependencies right from the repl.  In essence you can simply do: `gremlin> Grape.grab(group:'com.gmongo',module:'gmongo',version:'1.2')`.  Read more about this feature here: https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Groovy#use-of-external-jars

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have GMongo in the lib directory of Gremlin.

Comment: I did, the fact that I can import com.gmongo.GMongo confirms that the jar file is in the right place, I think

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your script in a file and then executing the entire file. For some reason in the shell the context gets lost. If you do an import and then execute another line, the shell won't remember the import.

This is what I end up doing - creating a file and then doing something like this:

./gremlin.sh -e my-script.groovy

Try that.

Comment: Next time, I try that. It works now, I had missed to add teh java driver. Thanks